# Dismissing 3 modal views

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I have a modal view controller on a modal view on another modal view.

I want to turn back the the first view but no matter what I do, it doesn't works....
I tried to dismiss the view with every available option but nothing happens....

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us the code you are using.

Comment: can you please show your code and what exactly you want to do...??

Comment: pass object of first viewcontroller and the then try as [viewCOntroller dismissMOdalViewContollerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I have a login view. after succeful login, I'm displaying a modal view controller. user choose something, and then another modal view appears. this modal view is a tab bar controller with 4 tabs and everytab presents a view...

Answer (score 0):

Use the completion block

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    // Delegate back to your second modal view and do the same thing    
}];
```

Might look weird with 3 dismiss animations in a row so I would use Animated:NO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are using xib or storyboard? If xib dismiss modalview should work if the name of the modalview is correct in your class. You can also use the ibaction for a button and dismiss your modalview and push a new view through the ibaction. If you are using storyboard use the modal option in storyboard. I have used the button action before when I have too many modals in one view before, since view controller class sometimes acts up. Just a suggestion and hope it helps. Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Well I used NSNotificationCenter and posted a notification with this:

```
-(void)dismiss{

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}